# Can a tail recursive function still get stack overflow?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, tail-recursion

I've been solving some challenges at codesignal.com using C-Lisp to learn it and I've been avoiding using loops to make lisp style code.

In this challenge called alternatingSums (which gives you an int array a that can be very large and ask you to return an array/list {sumOfEvenIndexedElements, sumOfOddIndexedElements}) i have been receiving stack overflow error with this code:

```
(defun alternatingSums(a &optional (index 0) (accumulated '(0 0)))

    (cond ((= index (length a)) 
                accumulated)
          ((evenp index)
                (alternatingSums 
                  a
                  (1+ index)
                 `(,(+ (svref a index ) (elt accumulated 0)) ,(elt accumulated 1))) 
          )
          ((oddp index)
                (alternatingSums 
                  a
                  (1+ index)
                 `(,(elt accumulated 0) ,(+ (svref a index ) (elt accumulated 1))))
          )
    )

)
```

isn't it tail-recursive or can tail-recursive functions still get stack-overflow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626736/common-lisp-why-does-my-tail-recursive-function-cause-a-stack-overflow?rq=1

Comment: Note that CLISP allows only Tail Self-Call Optimisation, a special case of TCO where only self-calls are optimised, nd not full Tail Call Optimisation. See this [article](https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html).

Comment: @Kaz I did see that post linked but that guy had a typo in his code and he even said he was sorry for posting that there. 
His addup3 calls an addup which is implemented with a loop as he said in a comment to one of the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive functions which call themselves from tail position can lead to stack overflow; language implementations must support some form of [tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to avoid the problem.

> I've been avoiding using loops to make lisp style code.

Common Lisp does not require that implementations do tail call elimination, but Scheme implementations must do so. It is idiomatic in Scheme to use recursion for iteration, but in Common Lisp it is idiomatic to use other iteration devices unless recursion provides a natural solution for the problem at hand.

Although Common Lisp implementations are not required to do tail call elimination, many do. Clisp does support limited tail call elimination, but only in compiled code, and only for self-recursive tail calls. This is not well-documented, but [there is some discussion to be found here](https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html) [@Renzo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460523/can-a-tail-recursive-function-still-get-stack-overflow/62464143#comment110469666_62460523). OP posted code will be subject to tail call elimination when compiled in Clisp since the function `alternatingSums` calls itself from tail position. This covers most cases in which you may be interested in tail call elimination, but note that tail call elimination is then *not* done for mutually recursive function definitions in Clisp. See the end of this answer for an example.

Defining a function from the REPL, or loading a definition from a source file, will result in interpreted code. If you are working in a development environment like SLIME, it is easy to compile: from the source file buffer either do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> to compile the whole file and send it to the REPL, or place the point inside of or immediately after a function definition and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to compile a single definition and send it to the REPL.

You could also compile the source file before loading it, e.g. `(load (compile-file "my-file.lisp"))`. Or you could load the source file, and compile a function after that, e.g. `(load "my-file.lisp")`, then `(compile 'my-function)`.

As already mentioned, it would probably be more likely that idiomatic Common Lisp code would not use recursion for this sort of function anyway. Here is a definition using the `loop` macro that some would find more clear and concise:

```
(defun alternating-sums (xs)
  (loop for x across xs
     and i below (length xs)
     if (evenp i) sum x into evens
     else sum x into odds
     finally (return (list evens odds))))
```

---

### The Case of Mutually Recursive Functions in Clisp

Here is a simple pair of mutually recursive function definitions:

```
(defun my-evenp (n)
  (cond ((zerop n) t)
        ((= 1 n) nil)
        (t (my-oddp (- n 1)))))

(defun my-oddp (n)
  (my-evenp (- n 1)))
```

Neither function calls itself directly, but `my-evenp` has a call to `my-oddp` in tail position, and `my-oddp` has a call to `my-evenp` in tail position. One would like for these tail calls to be eliminated to avoid blowing the stack for large inputs, but Clisp does not do this. Here is the disassembly:

```
CL-USER> (disassemble 'my-evenp)

Disassembly of function MY-EVENP
14 byte-code instructions:
0     (LOAD&PUSH 1)
1     (CALLS2&JMPIF 172 L16)              ; ZEROP
4     (CONST&PUSH 0)                      ; 1
5     (LOAD&PUSH 2)
6     (CALLSR&JMPIF 1 47 L19)             ; =
10    (LOAD&DEC&PUSH 1)
12    (CALL1 1)                           ; MY-ODDP
14    (SKIP&RET 2)
16    L16
16    (T)
17    (SKIP&RET 2)
19    L19
19    (NIL)
20    (SKIP&RET 2)

CL-USER> (disassemble 'my-oddp)

Disassembly of function MY-ODDP
3 byte-code instructions:
0     (LOAD&DEC&PUSH 1)
2     (CALL1 0)                           ; MY-EVENP
4     (SKIP&RET 2)
```

Compare with a tail recursive function that calls itself. Here there is no call to `factorial` in the disassembly, but instead a jump instruction has been inserted: `(JMPTAIL 2 5 L0)`.

```
(defun factorial (n acc)
  (if (zerop n) acc
      (factorial (- n 1) (* n acc))))
```

```
CL-USER> (disassemble 'factorial)

Disassembly of function FACTORIAL
11 byte-code instructions:
0     L0
0     (LOAD&PUSH 2)
1     (CALLS2&JMPIF 172 L15)              ; ZEROP
4     (LOAD&DEC&PUSH 2)
6     (LOAD&PUSH 3)
7     (LOAD&PUSH 3)
8     (CALLSR&PUSH 2 57)                  ; *
11    (JMPTAIL 2 5 L0)
15    L15
15    (LOAD 1)
16    (SKIP&RET 3)
```

Some Common Lisp implementations do support tail call elimination for mutually recursive functions. Here is the disassembly of `my-oddp` from SBCL:

```
;; SBCL
; disassembly for MY-ODDP
; Size: 40 bytes. Origin: #x52C8F9E4                          ; MY-ODDP
; 9E4:       498B4510         MOV RAX, [R13+16]               ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
; 9E8:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX
; 9EC:       BF02000000       MOV EDI, 2
; 9F1:       488BD3           MOV RDX, RBX
; 9F4:       E8771B37FF       CALL #x52001570                 ; GENERIC--
; 9F9:       488B5DF0         MOV RBX, [RBP-16]
; 9FD:       B902000000       MOV ECX, 2
; A02:       FF7508           PUSH QWORD PTR [RBP+8]
; A05:       E9D89977FD       JMP #x504093E2                  ; #<FDEFN MY-EVENP>
; A0A:       CC10             INT3 16                         ; Invalid argument count trap
```

This is a little harder to read than the previous examples because SBCL compiles to assembly language instead of byte code, but you can see that a jump instruction has been substituted for the call to `my-evenp`:

```
; A05:       E9D89977FD       JMP #x504093E2                  ; #<FDEFN MY-EVENP>
```

Comment: Note that CLISP does not support full Tail Call Optimisation (see this [article](https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html)).

Comment: @exnihilo: If someone told me their implementation supported tail call elimination I'd assume all tail calls were eliminated.  I'd be more wary about 'tail recursion elimination' which I'd assume might only mean recursive calls to the same function (self calls in other words).  So my interpretation is just backwards from yours.  I'm from a traditional CL background.

Comment: @exnihilo thak you very much for this answer, it was very instructive in many different layers

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp compilers are not required to optimize tail calls. Many do, but not all implementations compile your code by default; you have to compile the file using `compile-file`, or else the function individually with `(compile 'alternatingsums)`.

CLISP contains both an interpreter, which processes the nested-list representation of Lisp source code, and a byte code compiler. The compiler supports tail recursion, whereas the interpreter doesn't:

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (defun countdown (n) (unless (zerop n) (countdown (1- n))))
COUNTDOWN
[2]> (countdown 10000000)

*** - Program stack overflow. RESET
[3]> (compile 'countdown)
COUNTDOWN ;
NIL ;
NIL
[4]> (countdown 10000000)
NIL
```

Peeking under the hood a little bit:

[5]> (disassemble 'countdown)

```
Disassembly of function COUNTDOWN
1 required argument
0 optional arguments
No rest parameter
No keyword parameters
8 byte-code instructions:
0     L0
0     (LOAD&PUSH 1)
1     (CALLS2&JMPIF 172 L10)              ; ZEROP
4     (LOAD&DEC&PUSH 1)
6     (JMPTAIL 1 3 L0)
10    L10
10    (NIL)
11    (SKIP&RET 2)
NIL
```

We can see that the virtual machine has a `JMPTAIL` primitive.

Another approach to tail calling is via macros. Years ago, I hacked up a [macro called *tlet*](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/lisp-snippets/tree/tail-recursion.lisp) which lets you define (what look like) lexical functions using syntax similar to *labels*. The *tlet* construct compiles to a *tagbody* form in which the tail calls among the functions are *go* forms.  It does not analyze calls for being in tail position: all calls are unconditional transfers that do not return regardless of their position in the syntax.  The same source file also provides a trampoline-based implementation of tail calling among global functions.

Here is `tlet` in CLISP; note: the expression has not been compiled, yet it doesn't run out of stack:

```
$ clisp -q -i tail-recursion.lisp 
;; Loading file tail-recursion.lisp ...
;; Loaded file tail-recursion.lisp
[1]> (tlet ((counter (n) (unless (zerop n) (counter (1- n)))))
       (counter 100000))
NIL
```

`tlet` is not an optimizer. The call to `counter` is semantically a goto, always; it's not a procedure call that can sometimes turn into a goto under the right circumstances. Watch what happens when we add a `print`:

```
[2]> (tlet ((counter (n) (unless (zerop n) (print (counter (1- n))))))
       (counter 100000))
NIL
```

That's right; nothing! `(counter (1- n))` never returns, and so `print` is never called.

Comment: Note that CLISP does not support full Tail Call Optimisation (see this [article](https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html)).

Comment: @Renzo very interesting article you wrote there.

Comment: @MauricioRodriguez , I am not the author. I find it through this [link](https://40ants.com/lisp-project-of-the-day/2020/06/0103-trivial-tco.html).